# How to detect collision between SKSpriteNode and SKView SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode, skview

I have nine `SKSpriteNodes` that fall down from the top to the bottom of a screen. Also i have `SKView`, and I can drag it over the screen. How can I detect collision of my `SKView` with one of the nine `SKSpriteNodes` dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SKView` doesn't have `physicsBody` property, so it cannot collide.

You can, however, manually check if `SKView`'s `frame` intersects with `SKSpriteNode`'s frame:

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(skView.frame, node.frame) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the scene, you can detect collision between the frame and the SKSpriteNodes.

In your Scene.m, add the code in the `initWithSize:(CGSize)size`:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kSceneCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kSKNodeCategory; // this is your SKSpriteNode's categoryBitMask
```

and in `- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact`, you can detect the collision.